# How can I access request information while stubbing wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

How can I return(echo) the requested content-type and body?

```java
mockServer.stubFor(
    put(WireMock.urlEqualsTo("/echo"))
    .willReturn(
        aResponse()
        .withStatus(200)
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "@@?") // same as request.content-type
        .withBody("@@?")                   // same as request.body
    )
);
```

Or is there any alternative library that I can do this?